# Undefined index error in log

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm receiving the following error message in my log

```
Notice: Undefined index: und in include()(line 56 of /sites/all/themes/mysite/node--recipe.tpl.php).
```

Here is the line off code

```
$node->field_recipe_skill_audio[$node->language][0]['filename']
```

This error message is [well documented](http://drupal.org/node/1040748)  but i've been unable to get the fixes working. I have try the following request.

```
$node->field_recipe_skill_audio['en'][0]['filename']
$node->field_recipe_skill_audio['und'][0]['filename']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the notice error by checking if that field has data, e.g

```
if (isset($node->field_recipe_skill_audio[$node->language][0]['filename'])) {
  /* Do stuff */
}
```

or

```
if (isset($node->field_recipe_skill_audio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['filename'])) {
  /* Do stuff */
}
```

Comment: You obviously know your Drupal, but you've _got_ to stop using that method :P The proper API function to use is `field_get_items()`, it's language safe and future-proof. e.g. `$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_recipe_skill_audio'); if ($field_items) { // ...`

Comment: @Clive That IS the answer. If you add it, I will up-vote it. `:)`

Comment: @Clive, thanks. I was wanting to show how isset() or !empty() can avoid undefined index errors on arrays, in the context of OPs code. However, field_get_items or entity_metadata_wrapper, is indeed a better way to get the actual field items, particularly when dealing with multi-language content. Will use that next time!